# Get result from Postgres query contains only English word and letters

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres query that returns a column that contains multiple language words. I want to get only the results those contains A-Z and 0-9 only. How can I get the result?

```
Select name from table;
```

Comment: A regex query would do it. Checkout https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%2Bpostgres+regex+where+A-Z+0-9&atb=v110-1&ia=qa

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name ~* '\A[A-Z0-9]*\Z';
```

If you only want uppercase letters (not clear from your question), then use the case sensitive regular expression operator:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name ~ '\A[A-Z0-9]*\Z';
```

If you want at least one character, i.e. you don't want empty strings, change the `*` to `+`.

Comment: Error I get running this against a postgres database: Error running query: error parsing regexp: invalid escape sequence: `\Z`

Comment: What version are you using? Here's the relevant section in the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html